# Functional calculations with swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, functional-programming

- I have a structure (Runway) which consists of 2 points - in this case Lat/Lon.
- I have an airport which connateness multiple runways
- I want to calculate the bounding box off all the elements functionally in swift

I believe I can use the reduce function but I'm not 100% clear on how to do it.  My failed attempt was:

`runways.reduce(0, combine: { max($0.maxLat,$1.maxLat)})`

but I'm getting an error that Double does not have a member named maxLat ... ??

I also tried this:

`runways.reduce(0, combine: { max(((Runway)$0).maxLat,((Runway)($1)).maxLat)});`

which also doesn't work.

I'm sure this is a quick fix ... anybody?

## Playground-able code

```
struct Runway {
    let lat1 : Double
    let lat2 : Double
    let lon1 : Double
    let lon2 : Double
    let id1  : String
    let id2 : String
    
    
    var minLat : Double {
        get {
            return min(lat1,lat2)
        }
    }
    var minLon : Double {
        get {
            return min(lon1,lon2)
        }
    }

    var maxLat : Double {
        get {
            return max(lat1,lat2)
        }
    }

    var maxLon : Double {
        get {
            return max(lon1,lon2)
        }
    }
    
    init(Name n1 : String, Lat lat1 : Double, Lon lon1 : Double, Name n2 : String, Lat lat2 : Double, Lon lon2 : Double ) {
        self.id1 = n1;
        self.id2 = n2;
        self.lat1 = lat1;
        self.lat2 = lat2;
        self.lon1 = lon1;
        self.lon2 = lon2;
    }
}






///Airport class has min/max etc
class Airport {
    
    ///Airport Name
    let name : String

    ///Runway hodler array
    var runways : [Runway] = []
    
    func addRunway(rwy : Runway) {

        runways.append(rwy)
    }
    
    init (name : String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    
    func getMaxLat() {
       
        // Iterate through all runways and compare their max/mins

        // use reduce??
        
        // I'm confused!!
    }
}




/* Settings for Lancaster Airport */

//RWY 8
let lat8 : Double = 40.119946033333335
let lon8 : Double = 76.30404113333333

//RWY 26
let lat26 : Double = 40.12708346666667
let lon26 : Double = 76.2810583


//RWY 13
let lat13 : Double = 40.12317425
let lon13 : Double = 76.30378541666667

//RWY 31
let lat31 : Double = 40.11767828333333
let lon31 : Double = 76.29098628333334




var lancaster = Airport(name: "KLNS")

let Runway8_26 = Runway(Name: "8", Lat: lat8, Lon: lon8, Name: "26", Lat: lat26, Lon: lon26)

let Rnway13_31 = Runway(Name: "13", Lat: lat13, Lon: lon13, Name: "31", Lat: lat31, Lon: lon31)

lancaster.addRunway(Runway8_26);
lancaster.addRunway(Rnway13_31);


lancaster.getMaxLat()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
func getMaxLat() -> Double {
    return runways.reduce(-DBL_MAX, combine: {
        max($0, $1.maxLat)
    })
}
```

`$0` in the combine closure is the current result of the reduction, in your case a `Double`, and not an array element.
Therefore `$0.maxLat` as in your code is wrong.

Starting with `-DBL_MAX` instead of `0.0` ensures that the maximum is computed
correctly even if all latitudes are negative.